# Upload the multiple documents with same name

Tags: development-enviroment

According to sharepoint behavior it is not allowing to upload multiple documents with same name. But my clients wants to upload multiple documents with same name but may be with different meta data. Because the site is used by multiple people and they do not want to restrict based on the name only. Please suggest if we can do something to avoid this naming thing.

Answer (score 1):

-1 for mentioning Folders.

Give every person a **Document-Set** within the Library, this will also help with automagically assigning optional metadata.

When opened in Windows Explorer Document-Sets look and behave like Folders.
On the SharePoint side they do a lot more.

http://sharepoint.protiviti.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=171

If your client stills wants the files in one Library then ask them how they do it now on the FileSystem.

Comment: I stand corrected. Deleted my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In that case document have the same restrictions like the normal Filesystem. In the same path the filename has to be unique. Thats necessary for opening the documents via URL or at least opening the document library in Explorer view. You could create an Eventreceiver, which is changing the filename to a generic one after upload, but in that way you´ll lose the original filename (when the file is downloaded, it will do so using your generic filename, or when opening the document library, you´ll see many generic filenames).